# Path following logic brick wont make object move

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

I have a character wet up with the steering logic brick using path following.  I set up a nav mesh and set the character to target the player and use the nav mesh.  When I play the game the character turns to continue facing my character as I move around him but doesnt move from the spot i put him in.  I gave him a velocity acceleration and the like but dont know what wrong.

Comment: I think it is better to provide a demo file for investigation.

Comment: whats a good website/source to update to?

Comment: Try [blend-exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com). It won't steal your info and was made specifically for BSE.